# Basic programming JTable Model from resultset

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, tablemodel

it wont add the data, the columnames work, i am worn out i have no clue where to go from here. no error message just wont do it, it displays the object not the strings also i have no clue why it wont work since model.addRow() asks for an object[][] and i believe i deliver?

```
initComponents();
   try {
    PreparedStatement stat = Domein.dConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT domainid , domain FROM nabilpx84_hamchi.dnsp_domains");
        ResultSet resultaat = stat.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData naam = resultaat.getMetaData();

        Object[] kolommen = new Object[2];
        Object[][] data = null ;
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null,data);

        // kolom namen          
        for (int i = 1; i <= naam.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
            model.addColumn(naam.getColumnName(i));
        }
        //records

        data = new Object[1][2];

         while(resultaat.next())
        {
            data[0][0] = resultaat.getInt(1);
            data[0][1] = resultaat.getString(2);
            if(resultaat.isFirst())
            {
                model.addRow(data);
            }
        }

        uitvoerTabel.setModel(model);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Domein.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

// names of columns
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
    columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
}

// data of the table
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
    }
    data.add(vector);
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

In another hand, a service layer can helps you to decouple or have a service facade one or more repositories in your Swing application.

Comment: 1+ for good advice, especially the part about a service layer/façade.

Comment: thanks mate! Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>(); that confuses the hell out of me but i will consult my best friend google to see what is going on

Answer (score 2):

You've got some funky looking code in that you seem to be adding data *twice* into your table model. Why not instead create a DefaultTableModel with a column header Vector or String array and a row count of 0, and then add either Object array rows or Vector rows in your while loop?

Also you *must* create a new Object array or Vector for each row. You're not doing that in your while loop.

Something like:

```
    ResultSet resultaat = stat.executeQuery();
    ResultSetMetaData naam = resultaat.getMetaData();

    Vector<String> columnVector = new Vector<String>();
     for (int i = 1; i <= naam.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
        columnVector.addElement(naam.getColumnName(i));
    }       


    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnVector, 0);

    while(resultaat.next())    {
       // you must create a new Object array or Vector for each row
       Object[] rowData = new Object[2];
       rowData[0] = resultaat.getInt(1);
       rowData[1] = resultaat.getString(2);
       if(resultaat.isFirst()) {  // not sure what this is for
          model.addRow(rowData);
       }
    }
```

Also, please have a look at Rob Camick's Table from Database blog which you can find here: [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/)

Comment: well i add the columns first then the data(records) my brain works in mysterious ways so please feel free to correct my noobism

Answer (score 1):

I have my own class and i survive form this head ache 
if you need to fill any jtable just try this :

```
SQLGenerat sql  = new SQLGenerat ();
jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(sql.getRows("SQL code"), sql.getColumns("SQl CODE")));
```

Here is the Class you can use it

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author Azad
 */
public class SQLGenerat {
    Connection con;
    Statement  st ;
    ResultSet  rs ;


    public Vector getColumnNames(String sql)
      {
          Vector  columnNames = new Vector();
          /*
           *dont foeget to  wirte your connection 
           *before executing any sql statement
           */
          try{
              st = con.createStatement();
              rs=  st.executeQuery(sql);
              ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
              int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

              while(rs.next())
              {
                  Vector column = new Vector(columns);
                  for(int i = 0 ; i <= columns-1 ; i++){
                      column.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                  }
                  columnNames.addElement(column);
              }
          }
          catch(SQLException ex)
          {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          }
          return columnNames;
      }

      public Vector getRowDatas(String sql)
      {
          Vector rowDatas = new Vector ();
           /*
           *dont foeget to  wirte your connection 
           *before executing any sql statement
           */

          try{
              st = con.createStatement();
              rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
              ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
              int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();


              while(rs.next())
              {
                  Vector  rows = new Vector(columns);

                  for(int i = 0 ; i <= columns -1 ;i++)
                  {
                      rows.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                  }
                  rowDatas.addElement(rows);
              }
              rs.close();
              st.close();
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          }


          return rowDatas;
      }
}
```